# Authentication issues with MySQL Server on Centos 7

Tags: mysql, linux, centos, server

I am trying to configure mysql server to work with Centos 7 and I am having some issues with authentication.  I installed the community repo from MySQL and did

```
sudo yum install mysql-server
```

Next when I do

```
mysql_secure_installation
```

It says

```
Enter password for user root:
```

Since this is a fresh install and by default there should be no password set up as I've read in a million different places, hitting enter should work but it does not. By just hitting enter I get the following response:

```
Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

I have also tried every default-esque password I could think of and still no luck.  Has anyone else had this problem?

Comment: start mysqld with the -skip_grant_tables option (going off memory, can't remember the exact wording), to bypass the permissions system, then you can reset the pw.

Comment: I have tried that but if you start with skip grant tables it will not create the socket and you cannot connect to the DB

Comment: you sure? if there's no socket (unix or tcp domain), then mysql would be useless, and there'd be no point in having the skip option in the first place.

Comment: Im sure. If I try to run mysql_secure_installation i get

    Error: Cant connect to local mysql server through socket....

Comment: it should have an option to override the socket location from the command line, or there's a my.ini/my.cnf setting somewhere that's wrong.

Comment: Would that be the auto.cnf that you are talking about?

Comment: whatever config file(s) mysql has been told to look for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those having trouble with this I have figured out the problem.  There seems to be a bug in version 5.7.  Downgrade to 5.5/6 and proceed as normal.

Answer (score 0):

stop the mysqld service:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysqld stop
```

then
Start the mysql in Safe mode

```
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
```

try login with root as

```
mysql -u root
```

then try changing your mysql password